# Method named 'BEST' in multivariate analysis - what is it?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, multidimensional-scaling, ecology

I've read a few ecological papers where a 'BEST' procedure is used to assess effect of environmental parameters on biological community composition, after multivariate analysis like MDS. For instance in Kimball et al. (2014) :

" Effects of environmental parameters (temperature and salinity) on
community composition were analyzed with BEST relating the species
abundance matrix to the Euclidean distance matrix of environmental
parameters (normalized 30-day pre-collection average). "

Unfortunately, no reference is given for this method and obviously when I try to look for 'BEST analysis' or 'BEST procedure', the results are not relevant. Does anyone know something about this method or any scientific reference about it ? Thanks !

Reference : Kimball, Matthew E., Wendy E. Eash-Loucks, et Kathryn M. Petrinec. 2014. « Long-Term Changes in an Estuarine Mud Crab Community: Evaluating the Impact of Non-Native Species ». Journal of Crustacean Biology 34 (6): 731‑38. https://doi.org/10.1163/1937240X-00002287.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a function used by the Primer software.  It may be an implementation of BIOENV (or BIO-ENV).  See this documentation: [Explanation of Statistical Routines Using Primer](http://www.mdpi.com/1424-2818/3/3/329/s1).

Comment: Thank you very much, it makes more sense because I found in other papers the BIOENV procedure mentionned but nothing about the ' BEST ' function. Looks like they are the same thing !